# How to index words with their prefix in solr?

Tags: solr, stemming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how index words with their prefix in solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292975/how-index-words-with-their-prefix-in-solr)

I'm using solr 3.3. I want solr index words with their suffixes.

When I index 'book' and 'books' and search for 'book', solr shows any document that has 'book' or 'books' but when I index 'rain' and 'rainy' and search for 'rain', solr show any document that has 'rain', but I want solr to show any document that has 'rain' *or* 'rainy'.

Comment: Stemmers are unsophisticated tools. They may find a common stem for "organism" and "organization", but not for "dead" and "death".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming and http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/solr-stemming . I would consider " subtly suggesting" the user to enter nouns instead of adjectives.

Answer (score 1):

Related to your previous question, Stemming is already handling the 'book' and 'books' example. As @Jayendra answered, to get a search for 'rain' to return 'rainy', you need to implement a [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) and specify the synonyms you need that would match your desired search results.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use 'Hunspell' stemming which is based on OpenOffice dictionary files... http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Hunspell (Solr 3.5)